# Unable to create a button on top of a rectangle

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Here is a piece of code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class QuitButton extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    static JButton button = new JButton("Panic");
    Color[] colors = new Color[9];

    boolean pressed = false;

    public QuitButton()
    {
        button.addActionListener(this);
        colors[0] = Color.RED;
        colors[1] = Color.BLUE;
        colors[2] = Color.GREEN;
        colors[3] = Color.YELLOW;
        colors[4] = Color.BLACK;
        colors[5] = Color.PINK;
        colors[6] = Color.MAGENTA;
        colors[7] = Color.ORANGE;
        colors[8] = Color.CYAN;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Do NOT Panic!!");
        QuitButton qb = new QuitButton();   
        frame.add(qb);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //frame.pack();
        button.requestFocus();
        qb.gameLoop();
    }

    public void gameLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            repaint();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (pressed == false)
        {
            super.paint(g2d);
            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        } else
        {
            super.paint(g2d);
            Random r = new Random();
            int min = 0;
            int max = 8;
            int index = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
            g2d.setColor(colors[index]);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this program: The rectangle should be grey before but when I click the panic button colours should start changing.
Please don't get confused with the name of the class which is QuitButton.
But my rectangle is not occupying the entire window. Instead I am getting a teeny tiny rectangle like this : http://g.recordit.co/xJAMiQu6fM.gif
I think it is because of the layout I am using and I haven't specified anywhere that the button will be on top. Probably that's why they are coming side by side. I am new to GUI creation and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be making some guesses on how to do this, which is not a good way to learn to use a library.  Your first step should be to check the relevant tutorials on this, most of which will be found here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) Since this appears to be homework, I'm not going to give you a code solution but rather suggestions on how to improve:

- Override paintComponent, not paint since the latter gives double buffering and is less risky (less painting of borders and child component problems)
- In your paintComponent override, be sure to call the super's paintComponent method first to clear "dirty" pixels.
- Use a Swing Timer, not a while loop for your game loop. This will prevent your while loop from freezing the Swing event thread, a problem that can freeze your program. Google the tutorial as it is quite helpful.
- Do your randomization within the ActionListener's code (here likely the ActionListener for your Swing Timer), not within the painting code. The painting code should not change the state of the object but rather should only display the object's state.
- FlowLayout will respect a component's preferredSize, and your component's preferred size is 0,0 or close to it. Change this. Best to override `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` and return a Dimension that matches your Rectangle's size.
- Avoid using "magic" numbers, such as for your rectangle's size, and instead use constants or fields.
- Call `repaint()` within your Timer's ActionListener so the JVM knows to paint the component.

Comment: Sorry but please explain how the  component's preferred size is 0,0 or close to it. I would also like to mention that I am not follwing that particular tutorial for some reasons. The tutorials I am following appear to be quite jerky. They jump from things to things without explaining much and I found myself just going through their descriptions without making anything

Comment: @IshanSrivastava: maybe I missed something in your code -- I don't have my IDE here, but *where* do you either set the component's preferredSize or override `getPreferredSize()`? Again, I may have missed this, so please bear with me.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava: the best way to follow a tutorial is to experiment with the code that they give you. Play with it, and then try to incorporate it on your own and I have faith that you'll get it.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava: I've written quite a bit on use of the Swing Timer in other answers, some of which can be found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20%5bswing%5d%20animation%20timer). Please also have a look.

Comment: I am not familiar with Layouts. I went through half the tutorial and I had a few things in mind to try out before I went through the other half. This is the general kind of format they have been using and i just made up something. I am not aware of getPreferredSize()

Comment: @IshanSrivastava: Again go through the entire tutorial to gain a decent understanding of them. One key in understanding layouts is to know that JPanels can be nested, each using its own layout manager, and this can allow complex GUI layouts using simple layout managers. As for `getPreferredSize()` that is a method from the JComponent class (please check the [JComponent API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), the parent class for all non-window Swing components including JPanel. Simpler but not quite as clean is to just call `setPreferredSize(...)`.

Comment: Ok I will go through my entire tutorial first.